# PostgreSQL Importing CSV File Doesn't Import Fully

Tags: postgresql, csv, filemaker, pgadmin

This is sort of a general question here, as I cannot provide the data I am trying to import. However, I have exported a csv file from Filemaker Pro Advanced 15 and I am trying to import it into PostgreSQL using PgAdmin III. When importing this infromation, the progress bar fills and I am presented the option to click done (I presume the import is done). However, after clicking "done" and looking in the table, none of the data "imported" is actually there. I am not sure why this is, I have looked many places and have also contacted FM. Does anyone here have any suggestions ?
Here is the log for this execution:

```
2016-06-15 17:40:22 QUERY  : COPY query (127.0.0.1:5432):
COPY public."Clients"(name,"createdAt","updatedAt",age,birthday,canreceivetxt,phone,dln,ssn,zip,scndcntctprsn,casetype,incidentloc,dol,pdp,pr,incidentfcts,posncar,pdd,ymmov,advinfo,wtnsnfo,advtick,clitick,policy,adjstrnme,adjstrphne,adjstrfx,insclaimnum,advpol,advinsn,advinsp,trnsprtbprmdc,whtcmpny,medtrtmnt,prvdrs,doi,rltdclaims,wglss,source,notes,locov,dls,email,cai,advins,address,gender,scndrycntctprsonphone,scndryctnctprsnrel,inslimit,checksreceived,disbursement,clientinssettlesamnt,casefeepercent,advsettleamnt,"Casecost",lineitemfees,lastcall) 
FROM STDIN 
(FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER ',', HEADER, QUOTE '"', ESCAPE '"', ENCODING 'UTF8')
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with FileMaker. Unless you can show that the import works with *some* .csv file, and your question is how to produce such file when exporting from FileMaker.

Comment: I have imported with other csv files created by myself, but when doing a mass upload from filemaker this is what I receive

Comment: FileMaker exports standard .csv files. If you are sure this is an issue of the file format (and not, for example, file size), then show us an example of a format that works.